# how can I convert array to array (string format array to array)

Tags: sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array, slice

```
"SaveFile"
{
    "timestamp"     
    "2021-12-13 04:06:04"
    "team2"
    "de_dust2"
    {
        "team1"     "15"
        "team2"     "0"
    }
    "SecondHalfScore"
    {
        "team1"     "0"
        "team2"     "15"
    }
    "OvertimeScore"
    {
        "OvertimeID"        "2"
    }
    "History"
    {
        "NumConsecutiveTerroristLoses"      "4"
    }
    "PlayersAliveT"
    {
        "round1"        "1"
        "round30"       "63"
    }
    "PlayersAliveCT"
    {
        "round30"       "63"
    }
    "Timeouts"
    {
        "team2"     "4"
        "team1"     "4"
        "technical"
        {
            "team2"     "0"
            "team1"     "0"
        }
    }
    "PlayersOnTeam2"
    {
        "107020412"
        {
            "name"      "ImAGiraffe"
            {
                "item"      "weapon_knife"
                "item"      "weapon_usp_silencer"
            }
            "MatchStats"
            {
                "EquipmentValue"
                {
                    "round1"        "200"
                    "round30"       "200"
                }
                "MoneySaved"
                {
                    "round1"        "10000"
                }
            }
            "ItemCooldown"
            {
                "heavyassaultsuit"      "-42"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te4yO.png)

Comment: You didn't specify a language.... ? This looks like JSON (formatted) with the colons and commas removed. Why does it come in this stripped down format?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.